# WCF - ValidateUserNamePasswordCore() method in custom UserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator not called

Tags: c#, wcf, authorization, servicehost

I have defined an own [ServiceCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicecredentials.aspx) provider:

```
class PasswordServiceCredentials : ServiceCredentials
{
}
```

That provider generates a custom [SecurityTokenManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.securitytokenmanager.aspx) in [CreateSecurityTokenManager()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicecredentials.createsecuritytokenmanager) method when I start my [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx):

```
public override SecurityTokenManager CreateSecurityTokenManager()
{
    if (this.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode == UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom)
    {
        return new PasswordSecurityTokenManager(this);
    }

    return base.CreateSecurityTokenManager();
}
```

The *PasswordSecurityTokenManager* class:

```
class PasswordSecurityTokenManager : ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager
{
}
```

The instance generates a custom [SecurityTokenAuthenticator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.securitytokenauthenticator.aspx) in [CreateSecurityTokenAuthenticator()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.securitytokenmanager.createsecuritytokenauthenticator) method:

```
public override SecurityTokenAuthenticator CreateSecurityTokenAuthenticator(SecurityTokenRequirement tokenRequirement, out SecurityTokenResolver outOfBandTokenResolver)
{
    outOfBandTokenResolver = null;

    return new PasswordSecurityTokenAuthenticator(this.ServiceCredentials
                                                      .UserNameAuthentication
                                                      .CustomUserNamePasswordValidator);
}
```

The generated instance is a custom [CustomUserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.customusernamesecuritytokenauthenticator.aspx).

**The problem is** that the overwritten [ValidateUserNamePasswordCore()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.usernamesecuritytokenauthenticator.validateusernamepasswordcore.aspx) method is NOT CALLED at any time:

```
protected override ReadOnlyCollection<IAuthorizationPolicy> ValidateUserNamePasswordCore(String userName, String password)
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<IAuthorizationPolicy> currentPolicies = base.ValidateUserNamePasswordCore(userName, password);

    List<IAuthorizationPolicy> newPolicies = new List<IAuthorizationPolicy>();
    if (currentPolicies != null)
    {
        newPolicies.AddRange(currentPolicies.OfType<IAuthorizationPolicy>());
    }

    newPolicies.Add(new PasswordAuthorizationPolicy(userName, password));

    return newPolicies.AsReadOnly();
}
```

In my custom [IAuthorizationPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.policy.iauthorizationpolicy.aspx) provider *PasswordAuthorizationPolicy* I want to set a custom pricipal for the [EvaluationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.policy.evaluationcontext.aspx) in [Evaluate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.policy.iauthorizationpolicy.evaluate.aspx) method.

But if the upper method is not called, no additional IAuthorizationPolicy item can be defined.

What wrong or missing here?

I DO NOT use XML to configure my service, I do this 100% in C# code!

EDIT: The code ist based on the following blog article: http://www.neovolve.com/post/2008/04/07/wcf-security-getting-the-password-of-the-user.aspx

Comment: +1 for the source of the code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm only asking because you never mentioned anything about your config file in your post, but are you setting your serviceCredentials type in your serviceBehaviors?  Example:

```
<behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
     <behavior name="YourCustomBehavior">
       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
       <serviceCredentials type="Your.Namespace.PasswordServiceCredentials, Your.Namespace">
         <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
         <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" />
       </serviceCredentials>
       <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" />
     </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
```

And if you are, are you referencing "YourCustomBehavior" in your behaviorConfiguration on your service node?  Example:

```
<services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="YourCustomBehavior"
    name="Your.Service.Namespace.YourService">
     <endpoint address="net.tcp://..."
      binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfig"
      contract="Your.Service.Interface.Namespace.IYourService" />
   </service>
 </services>
```

It might be as obvious as that.

---

[image]
<sub>(source: [avivacommunityfund.org](http://media.avivacommunityfund.org/ideas/badge/id:13499/size:180x150))</sub>